# how to check an instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and am stuck: I have a model for Articles, Topics and Links. On the page, where the whole article is displayed, I show in div-boxes all `@topics` and all `@links`, which are connected to this article (`@topics.each` ...).
Sometimes there is/are no topic/topics or link/links connected to this one article and I don't want to show the div-box.
How do I test if the instance variable @topics is empty and therefore must not be displayed? Do I check this in the view or do I check it in the controller? Since I have no real clue I don't know where to start looking for.

Comment: If there are no `@topics`, then `@topics.each` should not create any `div`s. Same with `@links`. If you are erroneously showing `div`s when there are no `@topics` or no `@links`, then there is probably something wrong with the way you are setting `@topics` or `@links`. But, since you don't show any code, hard to say. Also, you might consider doing `@article.topics.each do |topic|` instead of setting a separate `@topics` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual pattern is this:

```
if (@topics.present?)
  @topics.each do |topic|
    # ... Show each row
  end
else
  # .. Show a "no entires" row.
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In the view, put your `each` loop under `unless @topics.empty?`.

Edit: But this does not cover the case when the `@topics` instance variable is not set at all. For a better pattern see tadman's response.

Comment: I prefer `if @topics.any?`, following the style rule that statements should be positive if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

I probably misunderstood your question.

Assuming:

1. You're doing this in `erb`,
2. You have a `@article` variable, and
3. Your associations are set up correctly so you can do `@article.topics`

Then I would think you could do something like:

```
<%- if @article.topics.any? %>
  <div class='topics'>
    <%- @article.topics.each do |topic| %>
      <div class='topic'>
        ... do some stuff
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Similar, naturally, for `@article.links`.

My `erb` is very rusty, so I might have gotten something wrong in there.